# Azure NodeJS Error: ENOENT, open 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\views\'

Tags: node.js, azure

I have been trying to deploy a Node application to Azure, but am running into a problem.  I think that I know the source of the problem, but am not sure how to change the config to fix it.

For some reason, my node process is looking to use D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin as the path to look for script files and views instead of looking at D:\home\site\wwwroot.

I get the error: Error: ENOENT, open 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\views\layouts\layout.hbs'
on the stacktrace, which means that my app.js is being called, but it is looking in the wrong place for the views.

How do I tell azure to go up one more directory to look for the layouts instead of using bin as the default?  Attached is the directory structure on my VM for the site.

**/site**

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                              
----                -------------     ------ ----                              
d----          2/9/2015   6:27 PM            bin                               
d----          2/9/2015   6:27 PM            controllers                       
d----          2/9/2015   6:27 PM            models                            
d----          2/9/2015   6:27 PM            node_modules                      
d----          2/9/2015   6:27 PM            public                            
d----          2/9/2015   6:28 PM            tests                             
d----          2/9/2015   6:28 PM            views                             
-a---          2/9/2015   6:38 PM       2448 app.js                            
-a---          2/7/2015   1:17 AM        634 config.js                         
-a---          2/9/2015   6:25 PM     202392 hostingstart.html                 
-a---          2/7/2015   1:40 AM        597 package.json                      
-a---          2/5/2015   9:37 PM         22 README.md                         
-a---          2/7/2015   1:18 AM       1236 routes.js                         
-a---          2/7/2015   1:49 AM       1801 Web.config                        
-a---          2/5/2015   9:37 PM       1671 Web.Debug.config
```

**site/bin**

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                              
----                -------------     ------ ----                              
-a---        10/21/2014  11:29 PM        629 ChangeConfig.ps1                  
-a---        10/21/2014  11:29 PM       2141 download.ps1                      
-a---         1/10/2015  12:46 AM      24256 Microsoft.NodejsTools.WebRole.dll 
-a---        10/21/2014  11:29 PM         17 node.cmd                          
-a---        10/21/2014  11:29 PM       1819 setup_web.cmd                     
-a---          2/5/2015   9:37 PM        272 www
```

**www**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('ExpressApp3');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

**app.js**

```
//...
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create(config.handlebars);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your Node.js application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=290972
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!--
    <add key="StorageAccountName" value="" />
    <add key="StorageAccountKey" value="" />
    <add key="ServiceBusNamespace" value="" />
    <add key="ServiceBusIssuerName" value="" />
    <add key="ServiceBusIssuerSecretKey" value="" />
    -->
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- mimeMap enables IIS to serve particular file types as specified by fileExtension. -->
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />

    <!-- Web.Debug.config adds attributes to this to enable remote debugging when publishing in Debug configuration. -->
    <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js;routes\*.js;views\*.jade"/>

    <!-- indicates that the server.js file is a Node.js application 
    to be handled by the iisnode module -->
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="/bin/www" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="app" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="iisnode.+" negate="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="bin\www" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Try replacing all `path.join(__dirname, ` with `path.join(__dirname, '..', `

Comment: Seems tobe on the right path, its now looking in D:\home\site   But, it's not a sustainable solution because nothing works on the local machine.

Comment: What does the directory structure look like? Where's app.js and www?

Comment: see above. it's posted.

Comment: i'm getting close. your suggestion was the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this issue today as well. I'm new to node, so I'm not sure if this is the best approach but this worked for me.

I added this early in app.js

```
process.chdir(path.join(process.cwd(), '..'));
```

Comment: I actually fount an even better way, again assuming this is ok to do.
add process.chdir(__dirname); to app.js

Comment: Actually process.chdir(__dirname); will allow the app to run on both local and Azure. If you use the "join" method, it doesn't work on my local

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it.

I moved the www file in my project from /bin/www to the root directory.
Changed in www:

```
var app = require('../app');
```

to

var app = require('./app');

Then changed my web.config to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your Node.js application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=290972
  -->
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <!--
    <add key="StorageAccountName" value="" />
    <add key="StorageAccountKey" value="" />
    <add key="ServiceBusNamespace" value="" />
    <add key="ServiceBusIssuerName" value="" />
    <add key="ServiceBusIssuerSecretKey" value="" />
    -->
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- mimeMap enables IIS to serve particular file types as specified by fileExtension. -->
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />

    <!-- Web.Debug.config adds attributes to this to enable remote debugging when publishing in Debug configuration. -->
    <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js;routes\*.js;views\*.hbs"/>

    <!-- indicates that the server.js file is a Node.js application 
    to be handled by the iisnode module -->
    <handlers>
          <add name="iisnode" path="www" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
     <!--  <add name="iisnode" path="bin/www" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />--!>
    </handlers>

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <!--<remove segment="bin" />-->
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="app" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="iisnode.+" negate="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
          <!--<action type="Rewrite" url="bin\www" />-->
        <action type="Rewrite" url="www" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue.
I had to downgrade visual studio code from 1.66 to 1.64.